# mysqldump best practice?

Tags: linux, mysql

When using mysqldump should I be using `--single-transaction`? should i always use `-q`?

What are best practices for dumping multiple MySQL databases? (`--all-databases`)

Comment: What are the purpose of the dumps? Just for backup purposes?

Comment: yes. Just for backup.

Comment: How big are the databases? The strategies for a small database will be quite different to one containing terabytes of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely going to depend on your requirements.  Read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqldump), use the flags to create the type of dumps you need, and then test the restoration.  Be careful with locking, as it will likely prevent your application(s) from working on varying levels.

There are numerous backup strategies for MySQL, which differ between engine types.  The same methods to backup MyISAM are not always able to be applied to InnoDB.  This topic is well covered on Serverfault, I suggest you search the site.

One of my preferred strategies:

- Replication slave for backups and a crontab to create nightly tarballs.
- Custom scripts that use mysqldump and mysqlhotcopy to dump small databases, the schemas, and the mysql database.

[Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start) is a useful tool.  If you have replication, additional tools such as [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) will be extremely helpful.

Comment: As well as the man page there's the documentation on the MySQL site. The seem to know something about this stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading through some of the posts on the MySQL Performance Blog (Author of the excellent book on the subject of MySQL Performance) relating to backups: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/category/backups/.  (Xtrabackup is covered).

Beware that the Maatkit tools are great for many tasks including dumps but probably not a good backup tool.
-ab

Comment: If you want to verify your replication slave and the resulting backup, Maatkit can be used as part of a backup strategy.